# Brightness control command on "startup Applications" is not working

Tags: 12.04, command-line, startup, brightness, startup-applications

On "Startup Applications" utility I added my suitable brightness to be configured each time OS is launched. But it is not working at all. I am having to bear system's very high default brightness.

the command is : `xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.5`

*Startup Applications* is very fine although. I have also added up firefox opening command which is opening it well.

This brightness command is working from terminal. How do i make it work from *startup App* ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install indicator-brightness 'bar for brightness control'

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install indicator-brightness
```

[image: opening]

[image: usage]

or

make it start on boot
install 
$ sudo apt-get install xbacklight

open the 'Startup Applications' then and add a 'new startup item' with the command:

> xbacklight -set 40

40 is the brightness lvl
from 1 => 100

don't use them both

Answer (score 0):

To set-up a predefined brightness on Ubuntu startup, type in the following command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

There add this line:

```
echo X > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

just before exit 0.

BE SURE not to place a value too low in place of X otherwise you will get a black screen.

Put values like 50, 75(my default value), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a executable text file and run that at startup. Open gedit, paste that line(command) and save it. Give the file executable permissions.
now add file to the start up list.